# How to prove that expessions like $\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}} - \sqrt{143} \notin \Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, algorithms, roots, rounding-error

### The Problem:

There are multiple "rooty" equations that can be simplified to a whole number, for example:

$$\sqrt{19 + 6\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{18} = 1$$
Because:
$$\sqrt{19 + 6\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{18} = \sqrt{18+\sqrt{72} + 1} - \sqrt{18} = \\ = \sqrt{18+2\sqrt{18}+1} - \sqrt{18} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{18}+1)^2}-\sqrt{18} = \\ = \sqrt{18}+1-\sqrt{18} = 1$$

However, in the title, we have the expression of:
$$\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}} - \sqrt{143} \approx 14$$
And using a scientific calculator you indeed get $14$ as the answer. But using a high precision online calculator you get the true answer of:
$$\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}} - \sqrt{143} = 14.00000000005032...$$

### The Question:

Is there a general way to prove that a "rooty" expression (like the one in the title) $\notin \Bbb{Z}$? Even if the expression is really close to a whole number, and **even high precision calculators can't give you the correct answer**?

Is there a **general procedure or algorithm** which tells you for sure that the number is or isn't $\in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Can you clarify what constitutes a "rooty" expression? Do you allow $n$-th roots for all positive integers $n$, or just square roots? Do you allow  division as well?

Comment: Rooty would mean any expression containing $n$th roots, $n$th powers, and the 4 basic operations of $+, -, *, \backslash$.

Comment: However, it would be nice to even get a way of solving the problem for more general expressions, like ones only containing square roots, $+, - ,$ and $*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K_0:=\Bbb{Q}$ and for $n\geq0$ define the field $K_{n+1}$ as
$$K_{n+1}:=K_n(\{\sqrt{x}:\ x\in K_n\})=K_n^{1/2},$$
and set $K:=\bigcup_{n\geq0}K_n$. Let $R\in K$ be a rooty expression, and let $n\in\Bbb{N}$ be such that $R\in K_n$. Let $x\in K_{n-1}$ be non-square. Then the map
$$\sigma_x:\ K_n\ \longrightarrow\ K_n:\ \sqrt{x}\ \longmapsto\ -\sqrt{x},$$
extends to a $K_{n-1}$-linear automorphism of $K_n$ that fixes $K_{n-1}$ pointwise. So if $\sigma_x(R)\neq R$ then $R\notin\Bbb{Z}$. On the other hand, if $\sigma_x(R)=R$ then $R\in K_{n-1}$, and we can repeat the same for some $x'\in K_{n-1}$ that is not a square. Eventually this will yield the minimal $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $R\in K_n$.

For example, for $R_1:=\sqrt{19 + 6\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{18}$ we have $R_1\in K_2$ and we would like to check whether $x:=19+6\sqrt{2}$ is a square in $K_1$ (clearly $18$ is a square in $K_1$ because $18\in K_0$). If it is, then it is a square in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and
$$19+6\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=(a^2+2b^2)+2ab\sqrt{2},$$
quickly shows that $(a,b)=(1,3)$ is a solution. Hence
$$R_1=\sqrt{19 + 6\sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{18}=1+3\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{2}=1.$$

We can try the same for $R_2:=\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}} - \sqrt{143}\in K_2$. We would like to check whether $x:=93+63\sqrt{85}$ is a square in $K_1$. If it is, then it is a square in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{85})$, but
$$93+63\sqrt{85}=(a+b\sqrt{85})^2=(a^2+85b^2)+2ab\sqrt{85},$$
is quickly checked to have no rational solutions. Then the automorphism of $K_2$ defined by
$$\varepsilon_x:\ K_2\ \longrightarrow\ K_2:
\ \sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}}\ \longmapsto\ -\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}},$$
fixes $K_1$ pointwise, and hence
$$\sigma_x(R_2)=-\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}}+\sqrt{143}\neq R_2,$$
so $R_2\notin K_1$. In particular $R_2$ is not an integer.

Comment: This is great, however, it only works for most cases. Consider an expression of the form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{x}} - d\sqrt{x}$, (that is close to an integer). Proving it for an expression like this would be tough, since you can't disprove that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x}) = \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: @DanielP I don't understand; either $a+b\sqrt{x}$ is a square in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x})$, in which case $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{x}}-d\sqrt{x}=u+v\sqrt{x}$ and you are done (it is an integer iff $u$ is an integer and $v=0$), or $a+b\sqrt{x}$ is not a square in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x})$ and then the whole thing is certainly not an integer.

Comment: @DanielP It becomes more complicated when you sum more terms, but this is *precisely* where this approach is nontrivial and *does* work.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I'm not too familiar with algebraic fields, I'll read your whole answer again and try to understand it even more.

Comment: I read your answer again, and I have a couple questions: $1$. How to show that equations of the form $19+6\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^2$ have a solution? You pointed out that you quickly got $(a,b) = (1,3)$ as the answer. How to get this solution though? $2$. Similarly, "$93+63\sqrt{85}=(a+b\sqrt{85})^2$ is quickly checked to have no rational solutions". How?

Comment: Expanding the squares yields
$$19+6\sqrt{2}=(a^2+2b^2)+2ab\sqrt{2},$$
and so solving $a^2+2b^2=19$ and $2ab=6$ yields the solutions $(a,b)=(1,3)$ and $(a,b)=(-1,-3)$. Similarly
$$93+63\sqrt{85}=(a^2+85b^2)+2ab\sqrt{85},$$
leads to solving $a^2+85b^2=93$ and $2ab=63$, which has no solutions. One way to see this is to note that $b=\tfrac{63}{2a}$ and so
$$93=a^2+85b^2=a^2+85\left(\tfrac{63}{2a}\right)^2,$$
but then $a$ is a root of
$$4a^4-4\times93a^2+85\times63^2=0,$$
which has no rational (or even real) roots.

Comment: Though I must admit I did not do any of these calculations; in stead I noted that the *norm* of $93+63\sqrt{85}$ is negative, so it is not a square.

Answer (score 4):

In this example, if $\sqrt{93+63\sqrt{85}}-\sqrt{143}=t\in\Bbb Q$, then
$$93+63\sqrt{85}=(t+\sqrt{143})^2$$
but that implies that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{85})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{143})$ which is false.
So, not only is your expression not an integer, it's not rational either.

This sort of argument will work for most expressions like $\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}-\sqrt c$ but not for all possible "rooty" expressions.

Comment: The question was with $\sqrt{143}$, not $\sqrt{14}$

Comment: @PeterForeman *mutatis mutandis*

Comment: Your argument would work for most cases, however, there might be expressions of the form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{x}} - d\sqrt{x}$, for which you'd get $a+b\sqrt{x} = (t+d\sqrt{x})^2$, and you **cannot follow the same argument** of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x}) \ne \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 3):

A more general method that works for these type of problems is to first find the minimal polynomial of the root expression (this is the polynomial of which the expression is solution and it's also of the lowest possible degree). There is an algorithm for this and you can use wolframalpha. This only works for algebraic numbers however.

For your example the minimal polynomial is $$x^8-944x^6-446946x^4-455778560x^2+112134658225$$

By the integral root theorem the divisors of $112134658225$ are the only possible integer solutions to this polynomial. The divisors are: $1,5,25,66973,334865,1674325,...$ and they get bigger and bigger. We also know that the root expression is solution to this polynomial and that it's close to $14$. However none of the divisors is anywhere close to $14$ so our root expression must be irrational solution.

This method only works for when the leading coefficient is $1$ but can be generalised even further with the rational root theorem.

I also recommend watching mathologers video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6AFxJdJYW4 which more or less should answer some other questions you may have.

Comment: - What if the divisors **are close** to $14$ though?

- And I've watched the Mathologer video, but those methods only work when the rooty expression **is exactly** a whole number, and I wan't to prove that it **isn't**.

Comment: @DanielP You simply plug in all values allowed by the rational root theorem; if none of them is a zero, then the minimal polynomial has no rational roots, and hence your rooty expression is not rational.

Comment: I've read up on the rational root theorem in the mean time, and it's a pretty smart approach. However, what happens if the minimal polynomial happens to have the roots $14$ **and** $14.00000000005032...$?

Comment: I don't think you will ever get such case in reality. You could technically construct such polynomial but if an expression seems to be converging to whole number and the root of the minimal polynomial is that number , it's almost certain that the root expression is then equal to that number.

Comment: Also check root separation of polynomials. There is usually a lower bound on how close two distinct roots of polynomial can be. Knowing the minimal polynomial you could figure out if having roots that close to each other is even possible and then conclude whether your expression is rational or not depending on that.